# Using Raw_Input to Check Existence of Directory

Tags: python, if-statement, file-exists

I am trying to design a block of code that checks if a user inputted directory exists, prints if it does, and if it does not.

```
import os

foldername = raw_input ("Please enter the name of your desired folder: ")

if os.path.exists(foldername):
     print "Yes, your folder exists!"
else:
     print "Please re-enter your folder directory as it does not exist."
```

The above is what I have, but it consistently outputs that the directory does not exists, despite me knowing that it does.

Insights?

python

Comment: Did you put absolute path? `/home/username/dir/` ?

Comment: Thank you! I'm very new to Python and this took me awhile to get!

Answer (score 1):

The code seems okay.

I believe that you aren't using the absolute path.
Try using `/home/username/dir/folder` instead of `folder`